# How to configure prometheus with alertmanager?

Tags: docker-compose, prometheus

**docker-compose.yml:**
This is the docker-compose  to  run the prometheus, node-exporter and alert-manager service. All  the services are running great. Even the health status in target menu of prometheus shows ok.

```
version: '2'

services:

    prometheus:
        image: prom/prometheus
        privileged: true
        volumes:
            - ./prometheus.yml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml
            - ./alertmanger/alert.rules:/alert.rules
        command:
            - '--config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml'
        ports:
            - '9090:9090'

    node-exporter:
        image: prom/node-exporter
        ports:
            - '9100:9100'

    alertmanager:
        image: prom/alertmanager
        privileged: true
        volumes:
             - ./alertmanager/alertmanager.yml:/alertmanager.yml
        command:
            - '--config.file=/alertmanager.yml'
        ports:
            - '9093:9093'
```

**prometheus.yml**

This is the prometheus  config file with targets and alerts target sets. The alertmanager target url is working fine.

```
global:
  scrape_interval: 5s
  external_labels:
    monitor: 'my-monitor'

# this is where I have simple alert rules
rule_files:
  - ./alertmanager/alert.rules

scrape_configs:
    - job_name: 'prometheus'
      static_configs: 
        - targets: ['localhost:9090']

    - job_name: 'node-exporter'
      static_configs:
        - targets: ['node-exporter:9100']

alerting:
  alertmanagers:
    - static_configs:
      - targets: ['some-ip:9093']
```

**alert.rules:**
Just a simple alert rules to show  alert when service is  down

```
ALERT service_down
  IF up == 0
```

**alertmanager.yml**

This is to send the message on slack when alerting occurs.

```
global:
  slack_api_url: 'https://api.slack.com/apps/A90S3Q753'

    route:
      receiver: 'slack'

    receivers:
      - name: 'slack'
        slack_configs:
          - send_resolved: true
            username: 'tara gurung'
            channel: '#general'
            api_url: 'https://hooks.slack.com/services/T52GRFN3F/B90NMV1U2/QKj1pZu3ZVY0QONyI5sfsdf'
```

**Problems:**
All the containers are working fine I am not able to figure out the exact problem.What am I really missing. Checking the alerts in prometheus shows.

**Alerts
No alerting rules defined**

[image]

Comment: would you please add the structure of the project and directories to your post?

Comment: tip: you don't need to map node-exporter to the host port. it will be accessible from within the contianer runtime and prometheus. This is if you are not accessing node exporter from elsewhere.
A common thing to remember which port to connect to is to use the docker compose tag, now deprecated", "expose".

That of course goes for alertmanager as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your `./alertmanager/alert.rules` file is not included in your docker config, so it is not available in the container. You need to add it to the prometheus service:

```
prometheus:
    image: prom/prometheus
    privileged: true
    volumes:
        - ./prometheus.yml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml
        - ./alertmanager/alert.rules:/alertmanager/alert.rules
    command:
        - '--config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml'

    ports:
        - '9090:9090'
```

And probably give an absolute path inside `prometheus.yml`:

```
rule_files:
- "/alertmanager/alert.rules"
```

You also need to make sure you alerting rules are valid. Please see the [prometheus docs](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/alerting_rules/) for details and examples. You `alert.rules` file should look something like this:

```
groups:
- name: example
  rules:

  # Alert for any instance that is unreachable for >5 minutes.
  - alert: InstanceDown
    expr: up == 0
    for: 5m
```

Once you have multiple files, it may be better to add the entire directory as a volume rather than individual files.

Moreover, you have not specified the correct hostname to the alertmanager in your prometheus.yml file.
If you are using the shown docker compose configuration it should be:

```
alerting:
  alertmanagers:
    - static_configs:
      - targets:
        - 'alertmanager:9093'
```

Based on:

```
alertmanager:
    image: prom/alertmanager
    privileged: true
    volumes:
         - ./alertmanager/alertmanager.yml:/alertmanager.yml
    command:
        - '--config.file=/alertmanager.yml'
    ports:
        - '9093:9093'
```

Comment: Added the volume `volumes:- ./alertmanager/alert.rules:/alert.rule` in alertmanger service in the docker-compose file but that didn't solve either

Comment: `alert.rules` is for prometheus, not alertmanager (it's specified in the prometheus config after all). Try adding it to the prometheus service instead.

Comment: Yes added prometheus but still didn't solve the problem the rules in prometheus shows nothing in prometheus server

Comment: Please update the configs as you have them now. You may also want to show the current working directory for prometheus ("status -> runtime and build information"). My guess is that the path is wrong.

Comment: Please edit your question, don't link to external resources. In your new config, the path inside the container is `/alert.rules`, but `prometheus.yml` has `alertmanager/alert.rules`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164334/discussion-between-tara-prasad-gurung-and-marc).

Comment: If it's still not working, please edit your question with all config changes. And double check your paths.

Comment: I don't see any path issues . where exactly I am going wrong not able to figure out the path problem. Is it we only pass the config file path in alertmanger and the rules goes in prometheus

Comment: `./alertmanager/alert.rules` is specified in `prometheus.yml`, and is used by prometheus only, not alertmanager. The link you posted above sets the wrong path inside the container so prometheus can't find the file. Again: please edit your question with the config containing the `alert.rules` file.

Comment: Your paths are still wrong. You're putting the file in `/alert.rules` in the container, but prometheus is looking for `./alertmanager/alert.rules`. They need to match. See my edited answer for the correct values.

Comment: Ok I have changed the path in prometheus to /alert.rules and now I am getting this issues . `Error loading config one or more errors occurred while applying the new configuration (--config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml)"` . Must be another path issue again

Comment: Your alerting rules is not valid syntax. Please see the [prometheus docs](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/alerting_rules/) for what they should look like.

Comment: Why does alertmanager and Prometheus run in privileged ?
Im not even running node-exporter privileged. What is the deal?

Answer (score 0):

If you need answers to this question see the explanation on this link
[How to make alert rules visible on Prometheus User Interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72011850/how-to-make-alert-rules-visible-on-prometheus-user-interface/72044960#72044960)

Your alert rules inside the prometheus.yml should look like this

```
rule_files:
 - "/etc/prometheus/alert.rules.yml"
```

You need to stop the alertmanager and prometheus containers and run this

```
docker run -d --name prometheus_ops -p 9191:9090 -v $(pwd)/prometheus.yml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml -v $(pwd)/alert.rules.yml:/etc/prometheus/alert.rules.yml prom/prometheus
```

Verify if you can see the alert.rule config path : Prometheus container ID and go to cd /etc/prometheus

```
docker exec -it fa99f733f69b sh
```