# How to make alert rules visible on Prometheus User Interface?

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager, prometheus-node-exporter

I am trying to set up some alert rules in Prometheus so that I can be alerted when an instance is down but when I click on the rules icon on the prometheus UI I see no set up config rules for alerting.

I am testing this locally on my computer and I have the docker prometheus, alertmanager, prom node_exporter and some other app listed on the

[image: Prometheus Targets]
[image: Prometheus UI Alert]
[image: Alert Manager UI]

Please help...

**prometheus.yml** file as shown below
PWD - /Users/spencer.ecas/ops/prometheus.yml

```html
global:
    scrape_interval:  15s
  scrape-timeout;  10s
  evaluation_interval: 15s
  external_labels:
    monitor: 'spencer'

alerting:
  alertmanagers:
   - static_configs:
     - targets:
       -  localhost:9093

rule_files:
  - alert.rules.yml

scrape_configs:
  - job_name: 'prometheus'
    scrape_interval: 5s
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['localhost:9090']
        labels:
          group: 'prometheus-server'

  - job_name: 'bis'
    scrape_interval: 5s
    metrics_path: /actor/prometheus
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['host.docker.internal:8790']
        labels:
          group: 'prometheus-bi-sanbox'

  - job_name: "node"
    scrape_interval: 5s
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['host.docker.internal:9100']
        labels:
          group: 'nodeexporter-server
```

**alert.rules.yml**
PWD - /Users/spencer.ecas/ops/prometheus/alert.rules.yml

```html
groups:
- name: alert.rules
  rules:
  - alert: InstanceDown
    expr: up == 0
    for: 1m
    labels:
      severity: "critical"
    annotations:
      summary: "Endpoint {{ $labels.instance }} down"
      description: "{{ $labels.instance }} of job {{ $labels.job }} has been down for more than 1 minutes."
  
  - alert: HostOutOfMemory
    expr: node_memory_MemAvailable / node_memory_MemTotal * 100 < 25
    for: 5m
    labels:
      severity: warning
    annotations:
      summary: "Host out of memory (instance {{ $labels.instance }})"
      description: "Node memory is filling up (< 25% left)\n  VALUE = {{ $value }}\n  LABELS: {{ $labels }}"


  - alert: HostOutOfDiskSpace
    expr: (node_filesystem_avail{mountpoint="/"}  * 100) / node_filesystem_size{mountpoint="/"} < 50
    for: 1s
    labels:
      severity: warning
    annotations:
      summary: "Host out of disk space (instance {{ $labels.instance }})"
      description: "Disk is almost full (< 50% left)\n  VALUE = {{ $value }}\n  LABELS: {{ $labels }}"


  - alert: HostHighCpuLoad
    expr: (sum by (instance) (irate(node_cpu{job="node_exporter_metrics",mode="idle"}[5m]))) > 80
    for: 5m
    labels:
      severity: warning
    annotations:
      summary: "Host high CPU load (instance {{ $labels.instance }})"
      description: "CPU load is > 80%\n  VALUE = {{ $value }}\n  LABELS: {{ $labels }}"`
```

**alertmanager.yml**
PWD - /Users/spencer.ecas/ops/alertmanager/alertmanager.yml

Here I am trying to forward the alerts to my slack channel

```html
global:
  resolve_timeout: 5m

route:
  group_by: ['alertname']
  group_wait: 10s
  group_interval: 10s
  repeat_interval: 1h
  receiver: 'slack-notifications'
receivers:
- name: 'slack-notifications'
  slack_configs:
  - api_url: "https://hooks.slack.com/services/T06J2AUUR/B03CYRJPBPC/HcgsYeG1jjbduwb"
    channel: '#alertmanager'
    send_resolved: true`
```

Comment: Please can anyone help out?
I have followed the correct procedure the best of knowledge

Comment: Thank you Emmanuel!!!!!!! This was all I needed. It works fine

Comment: Many many thanks!  I will try to add other alerting rules to the rule config file
God bless!±

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything seems properly done but the issue here could be how you spinned up your prometheus and alert-manager servers which are inside the prometheus.yml file.

Secondly on your promtheus.yml file, are you sure that the config file is reading the alert rules from

```
rule_files:
 - alert.rules.yml
```

So please edit the prometheus.yml file and under the rule_files use this path instead

```
rule_files:
 - "/etc/prometheus/alert.rules.yml"
```

I will suggest that you remove both alertmanager and prometheus containers and use the command below. The reason for spinning up prometheus container together with the alert.rules.yml config location is so that the alert.rules will be persistent on the prometheus container since the rules will be used on the prometheus server to trigger alerts

Make sure you create a directory like this before using the command
You should have the prometheus.yml file inside the `/Users/spencer.ecas/ops/prometheus`

```
docker run -d --name prometheus_ops -p 9191:9090 -v $(pwd)/prometheus.yml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml -v $(pwd)/alert.rules.yml:/etc/prometheus/alert.rules.yml prom/prometheus
```

This is just a better display of the command above - Treat them as the same

`docker run -d --name prometheus_ops -p 9191:9090 -v $(pwd)/prometheus.yml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml -v $(pwd)/alert.rules.yml:/etc/prometheus/alert.rules.yml prom/prometheus`